# Dynamically generate code from data?

Tags: c#, f#

There is a list of base data

```
type Record = { A: string; B: float; C: int; ...}
let Records: Record list = getRecordsFromDatabase()
```

And a list of rules,

```
type Rule = ｛ Condition: string; score: int ｝
let rules = ［ // The rules will be read from the database table
    { Condition = "=A"; Score = 5 };
    { Condition = ">B*.95 and <B=*1.05"; Score = 3 };
    ......
］
```

Then I need to test the rules against a list of new data against the base data and get the scores for each row and get the base row with the highest score (the sum of the scores for each rule). The rules will be stored in a database table and can be changed by users.

Is there any F# or C# library to help the implementation?

Comment: Will the "rule" syntax change?  Can't you just write a parser?

Comment: That's a rather broad question. You can use expressions similar to LINQ instead. You can use a parser generator like ANTLR. You can use a parser combinator like FParsec. You can use *none* of these, create a rule table in a database and compare data against the rule table

Comment: @maccettura, The "rule" syntax may be changed but I can control the syntax.

Comment: This looks like you're creating a rules engine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine

Comment: @mydogisbox Yes, is it any existing library for rule engine?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 You'll need to do some research to determine which one will be best for you (if any).